# Why am I getting only 800 hashes per second?

Tags: python, crypt, sha512

I was trying to crack a 6 character long password, but even after 10 minutes, it showed no progress. So, i decided to find how many hashes am I finding per second.

The following code need to crack the password, which is 'zzzz', h is the hash given by crypt, while s is the salt and hashing algorithm used.

```
import crypt
#zzzz
h='$6$XR2ZpTWwyJL90BVD$HpFiwwuLyHOVbWnk/G/gUW.Hz0SutY4F9io4zjWkLL8bK6F3A4WCdSWQNgtq8fTx6PuzM1cdyQdlN2Qv/HlzH.'
s = '$6$XR2ZpTWwyJL90BVD$'

def brute(hash, salt, charSet="abcdefghijklmnopqrtuvxyz"):
    # for pwd_len in range(7):
    for guess in product(charSet,repeat= 4):
        guess=''.join(guess)
        if hash == crypt.crypt(guess,salt):
            return guess
    return -1        

print(brute(h, s))
```

This is 456,976 hashes, but the time taken to crack the password is 9 minutes and 20 seconds, which is extremely slow. I know that single threading isn't ideal but isn't it still very low?

Comment: Well, hash creation ___IS___ slow … observe your CPU load while the program is running - if it is already running full load, multithreading won't help either. If it isn't, then use multithreading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `crypt` module, like the `crypt()` system call that underlies it, is meant for hashing passwords, and good password hashing algorithms are *designed* to be slow, precisely because they want to make it difficult for hackers do exactly what you're trying to do here.

In your case, if you generated your salt using the default arguments to [`crypt.mksalt()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/crypt.html#crypt.mksalt), each call to `crypt.crypt()` runs 5000 iterations of SHA-512, so your program actually computes 2284880000 individual SHA-512 hashes in the ten minutes it takes to brute-force this password. That should sound more reasonable!

You might want to experiment with changing the number of rounds passed to `mksalt()` to see how it affects the computation time.

Answer (score 2):

The `crypt()` function is intentionally slow to prevent such a brute force attack, by using "rounds" to calculate the hashes. The SHA-512 method uses 5000 rounds by default, see [the documentation of crypt(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html) this python module is based on:

> Since glibc 2.7, the SHA-256 and SHA-512 implementations support a user-supplied number of hashing rounds, defaulting to 5000.

A single run of the actual SHA-512 hashing function is fast.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your GPU to crack hashes with [hashcat](https://hashcat.net/hashcat/). For your case,

```
hashcat -m 1800 -w 3 -O -a 3 '$6$XR2ZpTWwyJL90BVD$HpFiwwuLyHOVbWnk/G/gUW.Hz0SutY4F9io4zjWkLL8bK6F3A4WCdSWQNgtq8fTx6PuzM1cdyQdlN2Qv/HlzH.' ?l?l?l?l
```

This took 4 seconds for my RTX 3080. It takes about 12 minutes to crack 6 lowercase letters.

Comment: hashcat was real quick even on my cpu, I will test on gpu as well. Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I can't upvote it because of reputation constraints, would like to add that the command would require hash within quotes to work on unix based systems

Comment: I added quotes. Thank you.